# Node JS e MongoDB - Retornar dados de um model para uma rota

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express.js

Sou novo com Node JS + MongoDB e estou com uma dúvida a uns dois dias que não consegui descobrir como resolve-la.

Meu problema é o seguinte:

Eu possuo um arquivo de rotas que fazem uma chamada para uma model, como no exemplo abaixo:

**Arquivo de rotas:**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
app.get('/api/hotels/', function(req, res) {
    let hotels = new app.model.Hotels();

        hotels.pageList(req.params.page, req.params.qtd, (err, docs) => {

            res.status(404).json({
                msg: 'implementation not found'
            })

        })
    })
}
```

**Arquivo de Models:**

```
'use strict';

function Hotels() {
    this._hotels = process.db.get().collection('hotels')
    this._ObjectID = process.db.ObjectID()
}

Hotels.prototype.pageList = function(page, qtd, cb) {
    //list all hotels
    this._hotels.find(function(err, hotels) {

        if (err) {
            return err;
        } else {
            return hotels;
        }
    })

    cb()
}

module.exports = function() {
    return Hotels
}
```

O problema é que eu não sei como posso devolver o resultado do model para a rota e exibir objeto JSON no browser do usuário.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola, primeiro ponto Bruno, utilize um ODM para realizar as operações de banco de dados com MongoDB (Mongoose, sequelize, etc...)

segundo ponto, a função de callback de pageList esta sempre retornando para o caller vazio. Ou seja, vazio para o erro e vazio para docs.

altere a implementação para:

```
Hotels.prototype.pageList = function(page, qtd, cb) {
    //list all hotels
    this._hotels.find({},function(err, hotels) {

        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        } else {
            return cb(null,hotels);
        }
    })  
}
```

Feito isso, verifique o retorno da chamada ao método pageList na instancia de hotels no arquivo de rotas. O mesmo deve conter todos os hotéis (se de fato existir no banco rs).

Última observação, ainda na função de retorno da chamada para pageLista no aquivo de rotas, você possui apenas um handler de erro, no caso vc retorna sempre o objeto { msg: 'implementation not found' } com status 404.

logo, será enviado para o cliente somente essa informação mesmo que o callback retorne o array de hoteis preenchido. Para gerenciar o retorno, faça algo como:

```
if(err || !docs) return res.send({code:500,msg:"Ops... Something wrong..."}); 
return res.send({code:200,msg:docs})
```

Bom, acho que isso deve resolver seu problema.